# Prove a relation is not well-founded

Tags: coq

Recall the definition of a well-founded relation from Coq's library :

```
Inductive Acc (A : Set) (R : A -> A -> Prop) (x : A) : Prop :=
  Acc_intro : (forall y : A, R y x -> Acc A R y) -> Acc A R x.

Definition well_founded (A : Set) (R : A -> A -> Prop) :=
  forall x : A, Acc A R x.
```

In other words, if all the predecessors `y` of an element `x` are accessible, then `x` is accessible too. This Coq definition accepts all usual mathematical well-founded relations, for example the strict order `<` on the natural numbers.

However, how can we prove that the strict order on the signed integers is not well-founded in this Coq sense ? As a constructive proof of a negation, we would start by assuming by contradiction that the order on signed integers is well-founded. That means all signed integers are accessible. Where is the contradiction in that ? `Acc_intro` looks happy with it.

But if we axiomatize that the order on signed integers is well-founded, we will be able to define a function recursively on them. The computation of this function will be an infinite loop, which seems to break the consistency of Coq's logic.

Did I make a mistake somewhere ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `<` were well-founded on the integers, the following function would terminate:

```
f : Z -> False
f x = f (x - 1)
```

Thus, `f 0` would yield a proof of `False`.  We can formalize this argument in Coq as follows:

```
Require Import Coq.ZArith.ZArith.

Lemma Z_lt_not_well_founded : ~ well_founded Z.lt.
Proof.
intros Hwf.
exact (Fix Hwf (fun _ => False) (fun x IH => IH (Z.pred x) (Z.lt_pred_l x)) 0%Z).
Qed.
```

Comment: Let me provide some intuition behind the proof. Informally speaking, if for an *arbitrary* element of the type (and corresponding relation) under consideration we can provide a predecessor then the relation is *not* well-founded. E.g. we can prove `~ well_founded Nat.le`, because e.g. for any `n` holds `Nat.pred  n <= n`.

Comment: @AntonTrunov I guess you meant `n <= n`. I now see that recursive definitions are regular `Fixpoint`s, structurally decreasing of the proofs of accessibility. `Fix` just factors out the proof that all elements are accessible, ie that the relation is well-founded.

Comment: @V.Semeria I actually meant pred. Arthur’s proof can be easily modified to prove my statement for nat and le.